# Acumatica - Error Creating SalesOrder - Variant/Subitem cannot be empty - REST API

Tags: json, http, postman, acumatica

I am currently doing some testing using Postman with the Acumatica REST Api.  I am trying to create a Sales Order using a PUT reqeust to the Sales Order endpoint.  I can tell I'm reaching the right endpoint and am starting to create a sales order, but I keep getting an error that Subitem cannot be empty, even though I'm attempting to pass a value to it. Here is the body of my PUT request:

```
{
    "OrderType" : {value: "QT"},
    "CustomerID" : {value: 300000014},
    "Details" : 
    [
        {
            "InventoryID" : {"value" : "001"},
            "Subitem" : {"value" : "U"},
            "Quantity": {"value" : 1}
        },
        {
            "InventoryID" : {"value" : "002"},
            "Subitem" : {"value" : "U"},
            "Quantity": {"value" : 3}
        }
    ]
}
```

And this is the error I receive:

```
{
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "PX.Data.PXException: Error: 'Subitem' cannot be empty.\r\n ---> PX.Data.PXOuterException: Error: Inserting  'Sales Order Line' record raised at least one error. Please review the errors.\r\n   at PX.Data.PXUIFieldAttribute.CommandPreparing(PXCache sender, PXCommandPreparingEventArgs e)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache.OnCommandPreparing(String name, Object row, Object value, PXDBOperation operation, Type table, FieldDescription& description)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.PersistInserted(Object row)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXCache`1.Persist(PXDBOperation operation)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist(Type cacheType, PXDBOperation operation)\r\n   at PX.Data.PXGraph.Persist()\r\n   at PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderEntry.Persist()\r\n   at SuperiorText.SOOrderEntryExt.Persist(PersistDelegate baseMethod) in C:\\Users\\csilva\\Source\\Repos\\SuperiorText\\SuperiorText\\SOOrderEntryExt.cs:line 23\r\n   at PX.Data.PXSave`1.<Handler>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__31.MoveNext()\r\n   at PX.Data.PXAction`1.<Press>d__31.MoveNext()\r\n   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.a(Object A_0, PXFilterRow[] A_1, PXFilterRow[] A_2)\r\n   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper.ExportTable()\r\n   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---",
    "exceptionType": "PX.Api.ContractBased.OutcomeEntityHasErrorsException",
    "stackTrace": "   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.GetOperationResult(EntityImpl entity, EntityExportContextBuilder entityExportContextBuilder, PXSYTable exportedKeys, List`1 errors)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.Put(ISystemContract systemContract, String version, String name, EntityImpl entity, CbOperationContext operationContext)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.EntityGateBase.PutImpl(EntityImpl entity)\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

I have tried variations on both the sub item key (eg "Subitem", "SubItemID", and "Variant") as well as tried both integers and strings as the value (eg "U", 0).  I have had no luck thus far.

How do I correctly target and assign the subitem value for a line item in a sales order?  And also, is there good documentation for this anywhere? The ones that I've come across so far have not been comprehensive enough in this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got it sorted, hopefully this info will help anyone else that finds themselves in a similar situation.

As @HB_ACUMATIA pointed out, Acumatica's Default 6.00.001 endpoint does not include functionality to allow the assigning of the Subitem field for some reason.  So, an extension of the Default is what got this working.  Here is an image that should get the point across on what to do:
[image]

Just need to go to the Web Service Endpoints page (System>Integration>Web Service Endpoints), select the Default one and extend it.  I named mine CustomDefault.  Then find the page to modify (SalesOrder in this case), and then the field (Details).  In the Fields tab, you can add a new field, name it what you want, and have it point to the mapped field you want to supply ("Subitem" mapped to Variant in my case).

Then modify the HTTP request to target this new endpoint (in my case, the bit between my company name and /entity/ changed from (W(blah)) to (W(8)), so make sure to also keep an eye open for that) :
http://localhost/YourCompany/(W(8))/entity/CustomDefault/6.00.001/SalesOrder

At first, it seemed like this didn't make a difference, but after a few minutes the address or request started to resolve correctly and I am now able to submit sales orders through the REST API.

Just as a final example, the body of my PUT request still looks like this:

```
{
    "OrderType" : {"value": "SO"},
    "CustomerID" : {"value": "300000014"},
    "Details" : 
    [
        {
            "InventoryID" : {"value" : "EXAMPLEPRODUCT"},
            "Subitem" : {"value" : "U"},
            "Quantity": {"value" : 3}
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT:**

It seems to be a bug in 6.00.001 endpoint.

When trying with this 6.00.001 URL endpoint it fails:
http://localhost/xxxyyyzzz/entity/Default/6.00.001/SalesOrder/

With the 17.200.001 endpoint it succeeds:
http://localhost/xxxyyyzzz/entity/Default/17.200.001/SalesOrder/

---

The most obvious explanation would be that because the subitem 'U' doesn't exists for the item '001'/'002' it gets set to null when validation are executed.

You can verify if this is the case quickly by going to the Sales Order screen and following these steps:

1. Insert one new record in Document Details tab.
2. Select Inventory ID for your '001'/'002' item
3. Click on sub item field (only visible if activated in the licence)
4. Press the F3 key

This will display the list of valid sub item values in a selector popup window. Make sure sub item 'U' exists for item '001'/'002' in there:
[image]

I did replicate the web service call successfully with Postman:

```
{
    "OrderType" : { value: 'SO' },
    "CustomerID" : { value: 'ABARTENDE'},
    "Details" : 
    [
        {
            "InventoryID" : { value : 'AACOMPUT01'},
            "Subitem" : { value : '0'},
            "Quantity": { value : 1}
        },
        {
            "InventoryID" : { value : 'ADMCHARGE'},
            "Subitem" : { value : '0'},
            "Quantity": { value : 2}
        }
    ]
}
```

It created a new Sales Order with the two items. I don't think your JSON is bad, try to double check yours with mine and get every minute syntax details identical.

For example notice that value is enclosed in quotes in your example:

```
"Subitem" : {"value" : "U"},
```

While mine isn't:

```
"Subitem" : {value : "U"},
```

Comment: Hi, I went ahead and followed those steps and, with a list of other available subitem values, both 0 and U exist for this item.  I have a feeling it has to do with levels of precision in the request that I'm making, but am not having any luck finding further info on this.

Comment: I did replicate your call with Postman and updated my answer with the JSON syntax that worked for me.

Comment: I tried changing mine to match the formatting that you use, but I have the same result. (the reason that I wrapped "value" in quotes is that that's how it's formatted when I do a GET for SalesOrder). Does your instance also require that Subitem cannot be empty?
Also, I cannot find the Subitem value when I do the GET for SalesOrder, which makes me wonder if it's further nested.

Comment: I do not get the Subitem either, I think this is done by design as that field is not included in the default endpoint configuration.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's a minute detail that is preventing the call from being successful. Would you happen to have an Acumatica instance that was created using the 'SalesDemo' data? Demo data section in link below explains how to deploy that. If you had that data it would be simpler to test as you could run the exact same request as I do. I see two possibility, either it's an error related to the data or json syntax. I can't reliably test against your data unfortunately but with sales demo data I could.  https://asiablog.acumatica.com/2015/09/perfect-acumatica-demo.html

Comment: I've finally replicated the bug. I think you're using 6.0.0.1 web service endpoint as I have the same error on that endpoint. Using 17.200.001 endpoint it works.

Comment: Yes that is exactly the version I'm using. We don't currently have Acumatica up to that version. We are still in 6.x. Do you happen to have any idea of a solution that will work in 6? I know the REST API is functional in 6..

Comment: You could try to extend the Web Service Endpoint to add the missing Subitem field. I haven't been successful doing that though.

Comment: Interesting, so in stock 6.x it isn't possible to create a Sales Order via the API?  Or is it something unique about the Subitem?

Comment: I'm not seeing Subitem in the 6.00.001 endpoint. It might be possible to extend it to add that field in it but I haven't been successful in doing so.

Comment: I found a solution. Will post another answer that has all the information in it.