# Error Adding New Sales Order via REST API - Acumatica

Tags: rest, acumatica, acumatica-kb

I am trying to add a new sales order, with detail rows, to my Acumatica system using the a custom endpoint I created at:

```
https://172.16.8.65/entity/ASG_INTEGRATION/6.00.001/SalesOrder
```

This is the JSON body I am sending in Postman:

```
{
    "OrderType": {  "value": "SO"     },
    "CustomerID": { "value": "6362212668"   },
    "Details": 
    [
        {
            "Account": {"value": "4040"            },
            "Branch": {"value": "00"                },
            "InventoryID": { "value": "33964"            },
            "OrderQty": { "value": 1.000000     }
        }
    ]
}
```

The reason I had to create the custom End Point was because the "Branch" field that I have on my detail sales order item **must** be included, and the Default end point did not have the Branch field in its populated fields. (Thanks to this [SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53071049/acumatica-error-creating-salesorder-variant-subitem-cannot-be-empty-rest-a) for pointing the way to that wrinkle!)

But now I get the following error (which does not tell me where to look for the error -- at least that I can see...):

```
{
    "message": "An error has occurred.",
    "exceptionMessage": "PX.Data.PXException: Error: The system failed to commit the CurrentDocument row.\r\n   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.SyStep.a(Object A_0, PXFilterRow[] A_1, PXFilterRow[] A_2) in C:\\Bld2\\AC-FULL2019R113-JOB1\\Sources\\NetTools\\PX.Data\\Api\\Export\\SyImport\\ImportProcessor.cs:line 3638\r\n   at PX.Api.SyImportProcessor.ExportTableHelper.ExportTable() in C:\\Bld2\\AC-FULL2019R113-JOB1\\Sources\\NetTools\\PX.Data\\Api\\Export\\SyImport\\ImportProcessor.cs:line 1171",
    "exceptionType": "PX.Api.ContractBased.OutcomeEntityHasErrorsException",
    "stackTrace": "   at System.Monads.ArgumentCheck.CheckNull[TSource](TSource source, Func`1 exceptionSource)\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.GetOperationResult(EntityImpl entity, EntityExportContextBuilder entityExportContextBuilder, PXSYTable exportedKeys, List`1 errors) in C:\\Bld2\\AC-FULL2019R113-JOB1\\Sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\EntityService.cs:line 480\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.EntityService.Put(ISystemContract systemContract, String version, String name, EntityImpl entity, CbOperationContext operationContext) in C:\\Bld2\\AC-FULL2019R113-JOB1\\Sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\EntityService.cs:line 474\r\n   at PX.Api.ContractBased.Soap.SoapFacadeBase.PutImpl(EntityImpl entity) in C:\\Bld2\\AC-FULL2019R113-JOB1\\Sources\\NetTools\\PX.Api.ContractBased\\Soap\\SoapFacadeBase.cs:line 117\r\n   at lambda_method(Closure , Object , Object[] )\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ActionExecutor.<>c__DisplayClass10.<GetExecutor>b__9(Object instance, Object[] methodParameters)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ReflectedHttpActionDescriptor.ExecuteAsync(HttpControllerContext controllerContext, IDictionary`2 arguments, CancellationToken cancellationToken)\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<CallOnActionExecutedAsync>d__5.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.ActionFilterAttribute.<ExecuteActionFilterAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ExceptionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__0.MoveNext()\r\n--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
}
```

Any idea where to go next in my debugging?

[Edit:Adding screenshots to address Fernando's question]

There are 2 possible branches, both named the same, and you cannot add both of them to an entity.
[image: Financial Settings Popup]

And this is in Document Details
[image: Document Settings]

Which one should I use? How can I know??? When I replicate what @Fernando shows (I assume using the Document Details "Branch"), I get a "Branch cannot be Empty" error:

[image: Branch Cannot Be Empty]

Comment: which Acumatica version are you using? Which endpoint (and version) was extended?

Comment: @Fernando - I extended "Default" version 6.00.001. Acumatica version 2019 R1. (Updated question with screenshot)

Comment: Are there any customizations in that page? It works correctly on my end. I followed these steps:
1-Extended the endpoint and added the Branch and Account in the Details entity.
2-Made the PUT request as shown here: https://imgur.com/a/J3cTI5w

Comment: Note: the title of your post should make reference to Sales Order, not Service Order

Comment: @Fernando - 1. Which "Branch" did you add? (I saw two of them). 2. There are some customizations to the page -- does that affect how the Endpoint works? (And I changed the title. Thanks!)

Comment: Im working with SalesDemo demo data. I used branch Capital (which is not the defaulted branch).
Here is my extended endpoint: https://imgur.com/a/xdkXz91
I would suggest testing the endpoint in an environment without customizations to help narrow down the potential cause of the issue

Comment: @Fernando: Working with MyStore, when I follow your steps, I get: Error: 'CustomerLocationID' cannot be empty. I can go looking for that field to add it -- but why do I get that error when you do not? Do you have CustomerLocationID in your populated fields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, my conversation with Fernando was helpful. Here's what I discovered, and here's what worked:

The fact that there are two different ways of selecting "Branch" in the Fields is significant.

One shows up in the "Document Details" PopUp
[image: Document Details Fields]

And one shows up in the Financial Settings -> Financial Information PopUp:
[image: Financial Settings Field]

As it turns out BOTH are needed. ***But they can't both belong to the SalesOrder Entity*** -- that's not allowed.

So, I extended the SalesOrder Entity with the Financial Settings "Branch"

[image: Sales Order Entity Extension]

And, I extended the SalesOrderDetail Entity with the DocumentDetails "Branch"

[image]

And then I could do this and it was accepted:

```
{
        "CustomerID": { "value": "76758" },
        "OrderType": {  "value": "SO"      },
        "Branch": {  "value": "00"  },
        "Details": 
        [
            {
                "Account": {  "value": "4040"   },
                "Branch": {  "value": "00"  },
                "InventoryID": {  "value": "33964"},
                "OrderQty": {  "value": 1.000000  }
            }
        ]
    }
```

Setting the branch in only one of those places would not create an accepted Sales Order record. So this worked and I have a new Sales Order, with a detail line in it.

I cannot remember now, because I tried so many different things, but, I ***believe*** that in the **18.200.001** version of SalesOrder, the Branch field already exists in the SalesOrder Detail, but not in SalesOrder. And in the **6.00.001** version it doesn't exist in either. I'm not sure, but I think that is how it is. In case anyone stumbles across this and is using a different version...